# Add new rules to singleton KieContainer by preserving existing rules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, drools, drools-guvnor

I am trying to add new rules to a singleton KieContainer having session persistence, in a Spring Boot project. I have implemented the programmatic approach for addition of new rules to the KieContainer but the existing rules are getting replaced everytime I update the ReleaseID of the KieContainer. What I want is to preserve the existing rules that is present in the Drools Session and add new rules to that. The updateContainer() function from my utility class is how I am making changes to the KieContainer.  Any suggestions mostly welcomed. My implementation is as follows:

**Configuration class:**

```java
@Configuration
public class DynamicDroolsConfig {

    private KieServices kieServices;

    @Autowired
    private IPersistentSessionService iPersistentSessionService;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        this.initDataSource();
        this.kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
    }

    @Bean
    public KieSession getPersistentKieSession() {
        List<SessioninfoEntity> sessioninfoEntities = iPersistentSessionService.getStoredSessionDetails();

        if (sessioninfoEntities.size() == 0) {
            return newSession();
        } else if (sessioninfoEntities.size() == 1) {
            return persistedSession(sessioninfoEntities.get(0));
        } else {
            // todo other things
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public KieServices getKieServices() {
        return this.kieServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public KieContainer getKieContainer() {
        getFileSystem();
        KieRepository kieRepository = kieServices.getRepository();
        kieRepository.addKieModule(kieRepository::getDefaultReleaseId);
        KieBuilder kb = kieServices.newKieBuilder(getFileSystem()).buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        return kieServices.newKieContainer(kieModule.getReleaseId());
    }

    @Bean
    public KieFileSystem getFileSystem() {
        KieFileSystem kieFileSystem = kieServices.newKieFileSystem();
        return kieFileSystem;
    }

    public Environment getEnv() {
        Environment env = kieServices.newEnvironment();
        env.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.drools.persistence.jpa"));
        env.set(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager());
        return env;
    }

    private void initDataSource() {
        PoolingDataSource ds = new PoolingDataSource();
        ds.setUniqueName("jdbc/BitronixJTADataSource");
        ds.setClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource");
        ds.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        ds.setAllowLocalTransactions(true);
        ds.getDriverProperties().put("user", "root");
        ds.getDriverProperties().put("password", "1234");
        ds.getDriverProperties().put("URL", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/drool_demo");
        ds.init();
    }

    private KieSession newSession() {
        return kieServices.getStoreServices().newKieSession(getKieContainer().getKieBase(), null, getEnv());
    }

    private KieSession persistedSession(SessioninfoEntity sessioninfoEntity) {
        return kieServices.getStoreServices().loadKieSession(sessioninfoEntity.getId(), getKieContainer().getKieBase(), null, getEnv());
    }
}
```

Container releaseId updation method:

```java
@Service
public class DroolsUtilityImpl implements IDroolsUtility {

    @Autowired
    private KieFileSystem fileSystem;
    @Autowired
    private KieServices services;
    @Autowired
    private KieContainer container;

    @Override
    public void updateContainer(String rules) {

//        System.out.println("drl:\n" + rules);
        fileSystem.write("src/main/resources/rules/rule.drl", rules);
        KieBuilder kb = services.newKieBuilder(fileSystem).buildAll();
        KieModule kieModule = kb.getKieModule();
        container.updateToVersion(kieModule.getReleaseId());
    }

    @Override
    public void viewContainerRules() {

        KieBase kieBase = container.getKieBase();
        for (KiePackage kp : kieBase.getKiePackages()) {
            for (Rule rule : kp.getRules()) {
                System.out.println(rule.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why? I don't see the utility of this functionality, just the massive overhead necessary to make sure that the rule you're adding is valid in the old context (eg no duplicate identifiers, things like that.)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I will be maintaining both singleton KieSession and KieContainer so I want to get the existing rules of the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to regenerate the pom and increase release Id. A bit like in this example :

```
  KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
  ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId("org.kie", "hello-world", "1.0");
  KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem()
      .generateAndWritePomXML( releaseId )
      .write( "src/main/resources/KBase1/org/pkg1/r1.drl", createDrl( "R1" ) )
      .write( "src/main/resources/KBase1/org/pkg2/r2.drl", createDrl( "R2" ) )
      .writeKModuleXML( createKieProjectWithPackages( ks, "org.pkg1" ).toXML() );
  ks.newKieBuilder( kfs ).buildAll();
```

taken from
https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c65b1cf1095a5000171b19f#L199

Comment: Is this pom xml referring the same maven pom.xml

Comment: It's the pom in your kjar. See the line `generateAndWritePomXML`?